# Node 4: Request path contains unescaped characters

Tags: node.js, openshift, npm-install

I'm currently trying to use Node on Openshift. Openshift builds my app inside a Docker container with node@v4.4.2 and npm@2.15.1.
When building the image using node 4, I get the following error, when npm install is run during the docker build:

```
1 util.go:91] npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 05:10:18
1 util.go:91] npm http request GET https://my.customregistry.com/foo/api/npm/bar/babel-core
1 util.go:91] npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-327.13.1.el7.x86_64
1 util.go:91] npm ERR! argv "/opt/rh/rh-nodejs4/root/usr/bin/node" "/opt/rh/rh-nodejs4/root/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-d"
1 util.go:91] npm ERR! node v4.4.2
1 util.go:91] npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
1 util.go:91] 
1 util.go:91] npm ERR! Request path contains unescaped characters.
1 util.go:91] npm ERR! 
1 util.go:91] npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
1 util.go:91] npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Initially I run the build on node@v0.10.40 with npm@2.14.13 where the install worked, but our app does not :P why I'm now trying the current LTS version of node. (Other versions are not available on Openshift)

My research has lead me to believe that the issue is related to proxy settings, but they seem to be set correctly through Openshift. Before npm install is run, the following output is in the logs:

```
1 util.go:91] npm info config set "proxy" "http://our.awesome.proxy.com:8888"
...
...
1 util.go:91] npm info config set "https-proxy" "http://our.awesome.proxy.com:8888"
```

Unfortunately `npm install`is always executed with the `-d`flag overriding log level settings set through env variables.

Am I unaware of any additional proxy settings that have to be set in node 4?

Comment: Just change the `env` variable that overrides `-d` flag

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the `-d` flag overrides the `env` variable. I get verbose output for the `npm config set proxy` command, but no verbose output during the `npm install -d`.